# NDSolve evaluation in a specific point

Tags: differential-equations, evaluation

I am trying to solve a differential equation numerically using `NDSolve`, as

```
s = NDSolve[{y''[x] + E^(4*(x + B/Sqrt[λ]*E^(-3*x)))*y[x] ==0,
             y[0] == 0.1, y'[0] == 1}, y[x], {x, 3, 5}] ;
```

I want to calculate the specific value of `y[x]` in a specific point. I tried

```
y[3.2] /. s
```

but all I get back is

```
y[3.2]
```

printed on the screen. 
How can I solve this problem?

I also tried the following code,

```
solution =y /. Flatten[NDSolve[{y''[x] + E^(4*(x + B/Sqrt[λ]*E^(-3*x)))*y[x] == 0,
                                y[0] == 0.1, y'[0] == 1}, y[x], {x, 3, 5}]];

solution[3.2]
```

but it gives the same problem.

Comment: Look at `s`: It's a rule of the form `y[x]->...`

Comment: What are `B` and $\lambda$?

Comment: I defined them the line above

Comment: If you have to evaluate at more than one specific point, the form `s = First@NDSolve[..., y, {x, 3, 5}]`, with `y` in place of `y[x]`, will be convenient.  See the first example under "Basic Examples", 4th input, in the documentation for `NDSolve`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, even in that case, I'd use `NDSolveValue` - it's just so much more convenient to use. I hardly find my self using `NDSolve` nowadays.

Comment: @user21 My main point for the OP was to use `y` instead of `y[x]` (or `y[3.2]`). Whether to use `NDSolve` or `NDSolveValue` seems minor, but I used `NDSolve` here because the OP did. That said, in analyzing a solution, I often evaluate expressions involving the variables and their derivatives (such as the DE, invariants, and other such functions). Having a set of substitution rules from `NDSolve` seems convenient, and if the degree of the highest derivative is greater than 1, then `NDSolveValue` doesn't return all solutions. (There are situations where I find `NDSolveValue` more convenient.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After specifying `B` and $\lambda$ you can use:

```
B = 1; \[Lambda] = 1;
s = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + 
     E^(4*(x + B/Sqrt[\[Lambda]]*E^(-3*x)))*y[x] == 0, y[0] == 0.1, 
   y'[0] == 1}, y[3.2], {x, 3, 5}]
0.01439636171252053`
```

Note that I did not use `y[x]` but `y[3.2]` to evaluate the interpolating function directly at `3.2`

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: Using `NDSolveValue` instead of `NDSolve` is really a very handy substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is,

```
B = 1; λ = 1;

s = NDSolve[{y''[x] + E^(4*(x + B/Sqrt[λ]*E^(-3*x)))*y[x] == 
     0, y[0] == 0.1, y'[0] == 1}, y[x], {x, 3, 5}];

Y[x_] = y[x] /. s

Y[3.2]
```

> {0.0143964}

**Note**

For some reason, the `SetDelay` is not producing the expected output.

```
Y[x_] := y[x] /. s

Y[3.2]
```